# Safe to pass instance of an Activity to another object?

Tags: android, architecture, memory-management

What I'm basically trying to do is pass an instance of my Activity to another object which will build the dynamic UI.

The main reason I'm doing this is to keep the Activity class clean.

Are there any repercussions when doing this? Will it affect the garbage collection and cause memory leaks?

Here is an example of what I'm doing:

Activity:

```
/* uses the instance of the Activity to build Views which are loaded from XML files (for non technical users to add content */
ContentHelper ch = new ContentHelper(MyActivity.this);
```

Should I keep the dynamic View building within the Activity, or is it alright to pass the instance to other classes to do this?

If I keep it in the Activity, it just feels bloated to me and much harder to manage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion it is not a good idea to pass the ACTIVITY somewhere - actually I'm not sure whether this will do anything at all.

What you can do is:

1 - You can create your own class, extending View class, build your UI there.
What you have to pass to that class is your activity context!

for example:

```
class Custom_UI_Builder extends View {
    public  Custom_UI_Builder(Context cxt) {
        super(cxt);
        // more stuff - your UI components...
    }
}
```

in the Activity that uses you 'UI class'

```
public myActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    myView = new Custom_UI_Builder(this);

            //what every else you need...

        mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this.getApplicationContext());
    mainLParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    mainLayout.setLayoutParams(mainLParam);
    mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            mainLayout.addView(myView, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 390);
    setContentView(mainLayout);

}}
```

2 - Then you can create an instance of your custom_UI_builder class in your Activity.

I'm not sure if this will have any unwanted effects on memory load.

Hope it will work!

Comment: I see where you're going, but that's almost the same thing I'm doing, except that you're extending the View in your class. You're still passing an instance of the Activity, which is my concern. The question was whether it's okay to pass the instance or not - it's a memory and design concern...

Comment: Yes - it is ok to pass the context. This can be done by passing to object, or by passing the result of this.getApplicationContext(). I think it is ok, regarding memory and design - you have no other way to pass it [I hope that I'm not misleading you]. The same thing is done in here - http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TouchPaint.html

Comment: I've decided to do something similar to what you said though (for now). I'm extending LinearLayout and building all the dynamic views within that custom one, which then gets added to the main view via the Activity - seems a lot cleaner.

Comment: yep - ok - it is similar. Only one thing: if you're creating some sort of list - you can use ListActivity? And you are talking about desing..which reminds me to tell you that custom view components cannot be described in an external xml file, as a resource. Describing the UI elements in an external file is recommended practise.

Comment: Yeah I know, but it's not really a list - a lot more complicated than that. It's based on a set of XML files which are populated by users (non-technical users). Sort of like a CMS for Android, so they can manage their own content. And this is all dynamic, so it wouldn't work with using the normal Android xml layout files (those are more for static views).